# How can I set callback function for requestPinShortcut of ShortcutManager in Android Studio with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A can create a Pin Shortcut of desktop, the following content is document of `requestPinShortcut`.

*Note the API will return without waiting for the user to respond, so getting TRUE from this API does *not* mean the shortcut was pinned successfully. FALSE if the launcher doesn't support this feature.*

I hope to do something when a user has created the Pin Shortcut, I think a  callback function  can do that, how can I create a callback function for `requestPinShortcut` ?

**Code A**

```
fun requestPin(context: Context) {

    val shortcutManager = context.getSystemService(ShortcutManager::class.java)

    val shortcutList = shortcutManager.pinnedShortcuts

    if (shortcutList.isEmpty()) {
        if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported) {
            val pinShortcutInfo = ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, SHORTCUT_ID).build()
            shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(pinShortcutInfo, null)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May be if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842627/android-how-to-receive-shortcut-create-result?